# rmarkdown dynamic title is not appearing unless a plot is belwo

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have this markdown document:

when you run it you will see the title "# group B my text for page" and 
"# group C my text for page" in text so the # is not being recognized as a header.

BUT if you uncomment

```
  #plot(i, main = "first plot")

      #plot(i*100,main = "second plot")
```

in the loop that creates those pages then you will see the # is recognized and the title is what it should be "group B my text for page" and 
"group C my text for page" and both are in bold.

It appears there needs to be a plot below:

```
 cat("my text for page 

...dslfjdlasjf kldsjf dsjafl djasklfj dasfjdasl jfdklsj fdklsaj dklsf")
```

for the header to work right. Why is that and how can it be fixed so that no plot is necessary below

````
cat("my text for page 

...dslfjdlasjf kldsjf dsjafl djasklfj dasfjdasl jfdklsj fdklsaj dklsf")

---
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    number_sections: false
    pandoc_args: [
      "-V","classoption=twocolumn"
      ]
    keep_tex: TRUE
setspace: singlespacing
geometry: margin=1.1cm
fig.lp: 'Fig '
always_allow_html: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage[usenames,table]{xcolor}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{tabulary}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE  , comment = NA, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
dat = data.frame(
  group1 = sample( LETTERS , 500, TRUE ),
group2 = sample( LETTERS[1] , 500, TRUE ),
var1 = rnorm(500),
var2 = rnorm(500),
var3 = rnorm(500),
var4 = rnorm(500),
var5 = rnorm(500),
var6 = rnorm(500),
var7 = rnorm(500),
var8 = rnorm(500)
)

dat = dat %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>% summarise(s1 = sum(var1),
                                                     s2 = sum(var2),
                                                     s3 = sum(var3),
                                                     s4 = sum(var4),
                                                     s5 = sum(var5),
                                                     s6 = sum(var6),
                                                     s7 = sum(var7),
                                                     s8 = sum(var8)
                                                     ) %>% as.data.frame()
rownames(dat) = NULL

groups = c("A","B","C")
class(groups)
```

```{r one, include= FALSE}
ta = data.frame(group = c("A,h","b, j "),`10-20`= c(1,"-"),`34-44`= c("-","-") ,check.names = FALSE)
ta

```

\newpage


# SUBJECT 1

my text for page 

...dslfjdlasjf kldsjf dsjafl djasklfj dasfjdasl jfdklsj fdklsaj dklsf

```{r echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='asis'} 


plot(4)

plot(66)

```


```{r echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='asis', fig.keep= 'all', fig.align='left'} 

for(i in 1:length(groups)){

  #cat(paste0("# SUBJECT ",i) )
  cat(paste0("\\newpage\n # group ",groups[i], "\n"))
  cat("my text for page 

...dslfjdlasjf kldsjf dsjafl djasklfj dasfjdasl jfdklsj fdklsaj dklsf")
  #plot(i, main = "first plot")

  #plot(i*100,main = "second plot")
  cat("\\newpage")
}

```

\newpage


```{r echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='asis'} 

library(xtable)
options(xtable.include.rownames=F) 
options(xtable.scalebox=.6)
options(xtable.tabular.environment = "tabulary")
options(xtable.width = "11 in")
options(xtable.comment=F)
options(xtable.floating = F)
#options("xtable.latex.environments", c("center"))
t = xtable(dat)
align(t) = "r|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|"
digits(t) = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
print(t, sanitize.text.function = identity,hline.after =      c(-1,seq(0,nrow(t)))          )

```
````

Comment: Try `cat("\n\n")` after the plots.  Sometime it needs two lines to properly recognize the different sections.

Comment: No my question is about NOT SHOWING plot. when the plots are not shown the title is messed up. # is not recognized

Comment: It doesn't recognize the `#` properly without adequate spacing and often misfires on the headers. Whether I understood it as about the plots or not doesn't matter.

Comment: ahh well in any case cat("\n\n") does not work

Comment: `groups <- c("group1", "group2", "group3")
for(i in 1:length(groups)){

  #cat(paste0("# SUBJECT ",i) )
  cat(paste0("\\newpage\n # group ",groups[i], "\n"))
  cat("my text for page 

...dslfjdlasjf kldsjf dsjafl djasklfj dasfjdasl jfdklsj fdklsaj dklsf")
  #plot(i, main = "first plot")

  #plot(i*100,main = "second plot")
   cat("\n\n")
}` works for me

Comment: So does `cat("\\pagebreak\n")` at the end.

Comment: hmmmmmm neither of those work. Can you post the formatted code?

Comment: Ok, if you're going to down vote me, I'll continue in the comments. Try putting regular markdown in the preheader item as `# my text for page` and see it that works.  Or use inline r code.  you can't cat() outside of R.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I think the cat is getting messed up by fig.keep= 'all', fig.align='left' somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me with "\n\n" at the start and end of the line so:

```
    cat("\n\n# Test Heading\n\n")
```